# UI move upward when keyboard open

Tags: android

I am making the UI of the application. When i tried to enter the value in the `EditText` then keyboard move the UI upward.
Please help me when keyboard open then it should not move the UI upward.

```
<activity
        android:name=".AddProductsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Comment: It might be happening because of the use of scroll view in that activity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It Solved my problem.

Thanks to all.

```
<activity
    android:name=".AddProductsActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use RelativeLayout for displaying Top and Bottom bar inside an another RelativeLayout, which covers whole screen.

for top bar :

```
android:id="@+id/top"
android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"
android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="<fix height like 50dp or as per requirement>"
```

for bottom bar :

```
android:id="@+id/bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

1. Now add a ScrollView like this:

   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/top"
   android:layout_above="@+id/bottom"
2. Now add a child view to this scroll view, which could be any out of RelativeLayout or LineareLayout. We need this child view to just wrap the other child views, which we want to add in the middle of the screen, now anything we want to see, just add that view as a child of this layout like EditText or anything you like.

Now when KeyBoard shows up, the middle scrollview will scroll upside, which won't distort your UI..

I hope it would be helpful, come back to me if you still have problem with this.. :)

Answer (score 0):

add following line your activity tag in menifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**  from  tag in manifest file to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm using TabActivity for my main activity and then FragmentActivity for my tabbed activities, the manifest settings seems not helping.  So, my solution is this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
    // Setup fragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Fragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Explicitly call setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE) on create.  Hope that can help some people if the manifest.xml doesn't help out.